# Get index of first occurrance of second string in the first String using recursion

Tags: java

```
public int indexOf(String s1,String s2){
   if(s1.length()<s2.length())
       return -1;
   else if(s1.substring(s1.length()-s2.length()).equals(s2))
       return s1.length()-s2.length();
   else 
       return indexOf(s1.substring(0,s1.length()-1),s2);                  
}
```

I wrote  this method to get index of the second string in the first one 
but it has a bug it cant effectively return  first occurrence of the second string  this is because I am using logic to find the second string from backwards and I could not think of any other logic. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
example of a failure case: firstString "BarackObama" second string "a"
```

Comment: Why would you want to use recursion to do this?

Comment: its just a programming exercise to get familiar  using recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, you are doing it backwards. Instead, you should go forward:

```
public static int indexOf(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1.length()<s2.length()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if(s1.substring(0, s2.length()).equals(s2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int i = indexOf(s1.substring(1, s1.length()), s2);
        if (i == -1) {
            return i;
        } else {
            return 1 + i;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
String s1 = "BarackObama";
String s2 = "rac";
indexOf(s1, s2);
```

It would run like this:

```
indexOf("BarackObama", "rac"):
    "BarackObama".substring(0, 3).equals("rac") -> false
    return 1 + indexOf("BarackObama".substring(1, 11), "rac")

indexOf("arackObama", "rac"):
    "arackObama".substring(0, 3).equals("rac") -> false
    return 1 + indexOf("arackObama".substring(1, 10), "rac")

indexOf("rackObama", "rac"):
    "rackObama".substring(0, 3).equals("rac") -> true
    return 0;

return 0 + 1 + 1 = 2
```

Comment: yes,this logic is very good but the problem is if the string is not present in first one it should return -1 as string function does

Comment: @deepakrao I did a quick fix. Try it now. I will update if I can come up with something better.

Comment: Thanks Anderson I completely forgot that we could use return type of the function. thanks a lot :)  I think still my brain has not become familiar with programming :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are using `subString(int startIndex)`, it would give you characters from the end. If you pass only on parameter to the subString method, it acts as the start index for the subString it returns. So in case your example, you would get the "a" at the end of "BarackObama". You can try to use `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

```
private int indexOf(String s1,String s2){
    int index=0;
    if( s1 ==null || s2 ==null){
        return -1;
    }else if(s1.length()<s2.length()){
        return -1;
    }else{
        index=s1.lastIndexOf(s2); 
        s1=s1.substring(0,index);
        if(!s1.contains(s2)){
            return index;
        }else{
            return indexOf(s1,s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int indexOf(String s1, String s2){
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()){
    return -1;
    } else {
        int n = 0;
    int index = findIndex(s1, s2, n);
    return index;
    }
}

private int findIndex(String s1, String s2, int n){
    if (s1.substring(n, (n + s2.length())).equals(s2)){
        return n;
    } else if ((n < s1.length() - s2.length())){
        return findIndex(s1, s2, (n + 1));
    } else{
      return -1;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a method that uses recursion to solve that program.